# get specific keys only from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying out MongoDB via mongoose for backup. Originally, I just store locally my JSON files and just sends copies of it in mongodb, so when the free server(on heroku) restarts it just gets all old data from mongodb thus this code

```
registrantid:number
name:string
idnumber:string
contact:string
photoid:string

async function resyncRegistrants(){
    const r = await Registrant.find({ "registrantid" : { $gt: 0 } })
    console.log(r.length + ' registrationpool records found');
    if (r.length === registrationpool.length) {
        console.log('Nothing to Sync');
    } else {
        console.log('updating registrationpool database...')
        registrationpool = r
    }
}
```

but now it got bigger and it hits the storage limit I'm supposed to work it to have it free so now I'm considering constantly get records from MongoDB and throw them piece by piece (like it supposed to)

Q1: Is it still advisable to store the whole registrationpool locally or just find and edit from mongodb when needed?

Q2: Can I just get the objects without the photo and get it later when needed as like this

```
async function resyncRegistrants(){
    const r = await Registrant.find({ "registrantid" : { $gt: 0 } })
    console.log(r.length + ' registrationpool records found');
    if (r.length === registrationpool.length) {
        console.log('Nothing to Sync');
    } else {
        console.log('updating registrationpool database...')
        registrationpool = []
        for (var i = r.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            let tempregistrant = {}
            tempregistrant.registrantid = r[i].registrantid
            tempregistrant.name = r[i].name
            tempregistrant.idnumber = r[i].idnumber
            tempregistrant.contact = r[i].contact
            registrationpool.push(tempregistrant)
            //is there a way to shorten this?
        }
    }
}

app.post('/getphotoid', (req, res)=>{
    if (req.body.getphotid > 0) {
        const r = await Registrant.find({ "registrantid" : { $eq: req.body.getphotid } })
        if (r.length===1) {
            if (r[0].registrantid==req.body.getphotid) {
                res.json(
                    [
                        {thephoto: r[0].photoid}
                    ]
                )
            }
        }
    } else {
        res.send('invalid registrantid')
    }
})
```

Comment: You can use _projection_ to control the fields you want  get from the server (as a result of the query). You can include / exclude fields of your choice.

Comment: @prasad_ does that mean i just add these ```const r = await Registrant.find({ "registrantid" : { $gt: 0 } }, ***'registrantid name idnumber contact'***)```

and the for statement will not be needed right?

Comment: The find method returns a _cursor_. The cursor gives access to the n number of documents returned by the query. The result can be converted to an array too (please see the API documentation). Projection allows that only the specified fields are returned for each document. The for-loop is to iterate thru the returned documents (if you want to, in your application for some purpose). See [Iterate the cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#iterate-the-returned-cursor)

Comment: ... and [projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections)